# How to load a raster into the Map Canvas using QGIS Action

Tags: qgis, raster

Is it possible to write an Action in QGIS that will load a raster into the current map canvas based on a url/path of the raster as specified in the attribute table of a shapefile?

The shapefile is a index-tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the code for this from [Tim Sutton Tutorials](http://blog.qgis.org/taxonomy/term/1).

What you are looking for is a combination of the two tutorials

- [Adding Raster to QGIS](http://blog.qgis.org/node/94) ([source here](https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/code_examples/4_adding_rasters_to_canvas/))
- [Working with Vector Attributes](http://blog.qgis.org/node/95) ([source here](https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/code_examples/6_accessing_vector_attributes/))

These are all C++ code. If you need python code. see [here](http://blog.qgis.org/taxonomy/term/2). But python tutorials are not exact port of C++ code. But Many Thanks to Tim.

Hope that helps